# Java Streams and System.in

Tags: java

When I read `System.in` by using a `Scanner` object's `nextInt()` method, it blocks until I write something and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But when I use it after `hasNext()` method like below only `hasNext()` blocks until I write something and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> combination on Windows).

```
while (input.hasNext())
{
    int num = input.nextInt();
    ... do things here
}
```

Can someone explain how exactly does this work? Does it use `\n` character or just waits me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key? Why doesn't this happen when I read a file (no blocking when reading a file). Aren't they both streams?

Comment: It most certainly does block when reading a file, but your computer is so fast you can't tell.

Comment: `hasNext`  consumes but buffers the content. It serves it to you on the next `next` call.

Comment: If you print in Java console you receive data in System.in only line by line. This is done so by design and there is nothing to tweak it. File IO works differently normally reading data chunk by chunk not blocking on special symbols.

Comment: Does it wait me to press Enter or it blocks until the stream has a '\n' character?

Answer (score 1):

1) In your code, "hasNext" is the one that will block waiting for the input. When "hasNext" returns, it means there is input available so "next" does not block.

From the JavaDoc for "hasNext":
*This method may block while waiting for input to scan.*

2) When reading from a file, all the contents are there (in the file), so "hasNext" will return true immediately until the end of the file is reached. So no blocking there.

When reading from System.in, the input is generated as you type, so it'll always wait cause it expects you to write some more data using the keyboard.

Comment: When I write something without pressing enter, is System.in affected?

Comment: I am not sure when System.in is actually modified, but from what I'm seeing here (at least in Windows), all of the "next" and "hasNext" methods wait until you press Enter. If you want to process each key pressed without having to wait for the Enter I don't think it'd be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

System.in is an InputStream (i.e. a stream) associated with the `stdin` (a file descriptor that comes standard with an operating system process) of the JVM process that runs your program on the given operating system.

What is happening under the hood is quite eloquently described in the seminal work [Advanced programming in Unix Environment](http://smile.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-Edition/dp/0321637739/) by Stevens and Rago. Basically, the Java implementation delegates to the standard I/O library (written/ported by Dennis Ritchie some 40 years ago!) implementation on your operating system.

Two characteristics of the standard I/O library are of essence:

1. It deals with streams, rather than files.
2. It provides **buffering**, an intermediate place in the RAM of your computer that is utilized before the input stream is read from or the output stream is written to.

The standard I/O library chooses the defaults for the buffer carefully and the whole thrust is to minimize the number of `read` and `write` system calls thereby reducing the CPU time required to carry out the I/O operation. Based on how the buffering occurs, there are three flavors of the streams: fully-buffered, line-buffered and unbuffered.

Now, in the above book, following appears in section 5.4:

> Most implementations default to the following types of buffering:
>   Standard error is always unbuffered. All other streams are line
>   buffered if they refer to a terminal device; otherwise, they are fully
>   buffered. The four platforms discussed in this book follow these
>   conventions for standard I/O buffering: standard error is unbuffered,
>   **streams open to terminal devices are line buffered**, and all **other
>   streams are fully buffered**.

This means that the standard input, by default, is going to be blocked (as if nothing happens) till you press the newline character. If you redirect the input from a file (e.g. `java MyProgram < foo.txt`) then you are reading from a stream that is fully-buffered by default.

There are some low-level details here, but when the program reads from the terminal device, it blocks for the newline character or EOF character to be pressed to flush the buffer. When reading from a file, since the stream is fully buffered, you don't notice that as the buffer is filled and flushed by the time your program starts reading it. When an EOF is read, in both cases, `hasNext()` returns false.